# Raspberry Pi 4 want boot Kali Linux, LCD screen shows "No Signal"

Tags: linux, pi-4, kali

I want to boot Kali Linux with my Raspberry Pi. I have downloaded ISO file for Raspberry from this [site](https://www.offensive-security.com/kali-linux-arm-images/#1493408272250-e17e9049-9ce8). When I power on Raspberry, the LCD screen just shows "No Signal".

HDMI cable is connected - I have booted Ubuntu Mate and it worked.

Comment: Which one did you download? "`Kali Linux RaspberryPi 2, 3 and 4`" or "`Kali Linux RaspberryPi 2 (v1.2), 3 and 4 64-Bit`"?

Comment: I have tried both, but none of them work.

Comment: Which HDMI you have tested? "HDMI 0" or "HDMI 1"? -- Change the `config.txt` to `hdmi_force_hotplug=1`.

Comment: Also, follow the suggestions of [this link](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=244431).

Comment: @M.Rostami thank you for your help. I have succeeded to boot kali by uncomenting hdmi_force_hotplug=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be the `config.txt` on your raspberry pi's `/boot` partition:

```
# uncomment if hdmi display is not detected and composite is being output

#hdmi_force_hotplug=1
```

As it said themself, uncomment this line would solve your problem.

```
# uncomment if hdmi display is not detected and composite is being output

hdmi_force_hotplug=1
```

In addition, check [this link](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=244431) out.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to M. Rostami's question, make sure your cable is firmly connected to your monitor. Also, make sure to check the screen resolution that was set from `raspi-config`.